# How to check the maximum bandwidth available for my network, without using any tool?

Tags: shell

I am trying to get the maximum bandwidth available on **eth0**. I can check the currrent speed of the network by going to /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes. Let say I am getting speed of 20Mbps. How to get if what total bandwidth available on this network? I am writing a shell script. I donot want to use any tool for this purpose!

Comment: What do you mean by _bandwidth available_ - network bandwidth capacity, network bandwidth consumption, throughput, …?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like wget and see if you can capture and process the resultant output.

something like this

[check internet speed using terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104755/how-to-check-internet-speed-via-terminal)